# How to read a sqlite text - field (not string) from SQLite database from Android App

Tags: android, sqlite, out-of-memory

I have:
a sqlite database with a table and a datafield of type `"text"` which holds big strings. The strings have the size of:

```
select length(mapdata) from mapobjects
```

result:

```
29386
94111
95558
127952
35593
```

I try to read the data within my android app as follow

```
    c = chronica_connection_read.rawQuery(sql, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
        String mapdata = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("mapdata"));
```

and I get:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 58792 byte allocation with 14504 free bytes and 14KB until OOM
   at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
   at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:438)
   at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
```

I guess the data is not that big, that it is real memory issue. I guess I am handling this wrong.
Any help with howto to read a text field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not reading data from your cursor correctly and you're stuck in an infinite loop

```
c = chronica_connection_read.rawQuery(sql, null);
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        String mapdata = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("mapdata"));

        // continue your work with the retrieved string
    } while (c.moveToNext());
}
```

You can also think about closing your cursor after job is done

```
c.close();
```

Comment: Just also found the issue. Am I stupid ? Yes I am. Thanks a lot for helping and sorry for wasting your time .